# Reportviewer send email via gmail

Tags: c#, smtpclient, report-viewer2010

I am working on a WinForm where a reportviewer is embedded.

How do I send email via gmail/yahoo and attach this report as a pdf? 
I looked at this post
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32109/Send-Mail-and-Print-Report-in-Report-Viewer-Contro but was not sure if it would work only with desktop email clients such as Outlook or will it support web based email client?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<.*?>";
static string StripHTML(string inputString)
{
  return Regex.Replace(inputString, HTML_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty);
}

public static void sendMessage()
{
  var username = "john.doe@gmail.com";
  var password = "password";
  MailAddress MailFrom = new MailAddress("john.doe@gmail.com");
  MailAddress MailTo = new MailAddress("john.doe@gmail.com");
  var subject = "TEST SUBJECT";
  var attachmentPath = "test.pdf";
  var mailBody = "<b>test</b>";


  NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

  System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
  smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  smtp.EnableSsl = true;
  smtp.Credentials = cred;
  smtp.Port = 587;

  MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

  mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

  AlternateView avAlternateView = null;
  Encoding myEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");

  avAlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(StripHTML(mailBody), myEncoding, "text/plain");
  mail.AlternateViews.Add(avAlternateView);

  avAlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailBody, myEncoding, "text/html");
  mail.AlternateViews.Add(avAlternateView);

  mail.Sender = MailFrom;
  mail.From = MailFrom;
  mail.ReplyTo = MailFrom;

  mail.To.Add(MailTo);

  mail.Subject = subject;
  mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"); 

  mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");

  Attachment attachment = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
  mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
  try
  {
    smtp.Send(mail);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
}
```